# Use \hapto with no hyphen after it for one .bib entry

Tags: chemmacros, chemformula

I'm using `achemso`, `chemmacros`, and `chemformula` to format a paper. I've written the whole document using the `coord-use-hyphen = true` option from `chemmacros`. However, now I hit a paper that that doesn't work for, and I'm wondering if I have to redo all my other .bib entries.

The easiest way would seem to be to make a `\haptonohypen{}` command that works like `\hapto{}` but does not generate a hypen, no matter what `coord-use-hyphen` is set to?

The other way would be if I could set `\iupac` to take an option for one entry (something like `\iupac[coord-use-hyphen=true]{stuff here}`, but I don't know if that is possible (I tried just specifying the above already}.

[Here is the paper, note that it has a `\hapto` with no hypen after it.](http://www.sciencedirect.com.proxy.lib.sfu.ca/science/article/pii/S0277538704004450)

Here is a MWE with the options I've used for my other 79 .bib entries:

```
\documentclass[journal=cgdefu]{achemso}
    \AtBeginDocument{\let\latin\relax} %So chemarcos works woth achemso

\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{
        formula=chemformula, %use chemformula instead of say, mhchem
        nomenclature/coord-use-hyphen=true, %Puts hypens after bridging and hapto
} 


\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@article{Masci2005,
author = {Masci, Bernardo and Thu\'{e}ry, Pierre},
doi = {10.1016/j.poly.2004.11.002},
journal = {Polyhedron},
number = {2},
pages = {229--237},
title = {{Uranyl complexes with the pyridine-2,6-dicarboxylato ligand: new dinuclear species with \iupac{\bridge{}\hapto{2},\hapto{2}peroxide}, \iupac{\bridge{2}hydroxide} or \iupac{\bridge{2}methoxide bridges}}},
volume = {24},
year = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents}

\title{MWE}
\author{Canageek}
\affiliation{TeX.SX}
\email{Canageek}
\date{}


\begin{document}

This is a test text.\cite{Masci2005}

\bibliography{MWE}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with v5.7 (2016/06/07) (or rather with v5.7a due to some typos) `chemmacros` uses the function

```
\chemmacros_coordination_symbol:nnnn
```

for defining the coordination symbols.  With this it is easy to define a suiting macro which never outputs the following dash.

Also starting with v5.7 `\iupac` has an optional argument for setting options which in this case may even be the better choice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}[2016/06/08] % v5.7a

\chemsetup{
  formula = chemformula
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \chemmacros_hapto_nohyp:n #1
  {
    \chemmacros_coordination_symbol:nnnn
      { \c_false_bool } % boolean: use hyphen or don't
      { \c_false_bool } % boolean: use superscript (true) or subscript (false)
      { \chemeta }      % symbol
      {#1}              % sub-/superscript
  }

\NewChemIUPAC \haptoNH { \chemmacros_hapto_nohyp:n }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hapto{2} \par
Option one: \haptoNH{2} \par
Option two: \iupac[coord-use-hyphen=false]{\hapto{2}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can define a `\haptonohyphen` command:

```
\documentclass[journal=cgdefu]{achemso}
    \AtBeginDocument{\let\latin\relax} %So chemarcos works woth achemso

\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{
        formula=chemformula, %use chemformula instead of say, mhchem
        nomenclature/coord-use-hyphen=true, %Puts hypens after bridging and hapto
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChemIUPAC \haptonohyphen  { \chemformula_hapto_nohyphen:n }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \chemformula_hapto_nohyphen:n #1
  {
    \chemeta \chemformula_superscript:n { #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Masci2005,
author = {Masci, Bernardo and Thu\'{e}ry, Pierre},
doi = {10.1016/j.poly.2004.11.002},
journal = {Polyhedron},
number = {2},
pages = {229--237},
title = {{Uranyl complexes with the pyridine-2,6-dicarboxylato ligand: 
         new dinuclear species with \iupac{\bridge{}\haptonohyphen{2},\hapto{2}peroxide},
         \iupac{\bridge{2}hydroxide} or \iupac{\bridge{2}methoxide bridges}}},
volume = {24},
year = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents}

\title{MWE}
\author{Canageek}
\affiliation{TeX.SX}
\email{Canageek}
\date{}


\begin{document}

This is a test text.\cite{Masci2005}

Uranyl complexes with the pyridine-2,6-dicarboxylato 
ligand: new dinuclear species with \iupac{\bridge{}\haptonohyphen{2},\hapto{2}peroxide}, 
\iupac{\bridge{2}hydroxide} or \iupac{\bridge{2}methoxide bridges},

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I used your answer, but figure I should put the new, official interface at the top.